# How can I get block comment hotkey functionality when editing *.ftl files in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, freemarker

Trying to edit Freemarker Templates in Eclipse, and going nuts because I have some inline Javascript that I'm creating on the fly, and can't easily comment / uncomment multiple lines at a time.

I've tried the following:

- expanding the scope of the "toggle comment" behavior (to things like "Editing Text", or "In Windows") - has no effect
- installing the official Freemarker eclipse plugin (both 1.0 and 1.1) - has absolutely no effect that I can see, other than appearing under "Preferences ... File Associations"
- associating the .ftl extension with other types of editors - HTML, JavaScript, 3rd party - all these have absolutely no effect that I can see

Is there a way I can tell if Eclipse is even honoring my file associations?  How do I know, for sure, which Editor is being used?  I know when a Java file is being edited, I see additional pulldown menus (Source, etc.) - is there any other diagnostic way to figure out what's going on?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this isn't what you want to hear, but the Freemarker support in [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) is really great.

Unfortunately, it isn't part of the free Community Edition, so you have to get the Ultimate Edition to benefit from it. But you can try it out for 30 days for free.

No, I am in no way associated with JetBrains, just a happy user.